# How can I know the length of user input with trailing whitespaces in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, string-length

I want to know the length of one line of the user input in Fortran. Since that input can contain some trailing whitespaces, LEN_TRIM does not give the correct answer.

```
program test

implicit none
character(len=100) :: s

read(*, '(a)') s
write(*, '(i0)') len_trim(s)

end program test
```

example inputs and outputs:

input: `Hello World!`

output: 12

expected output: 15

input:       (5 spaces)

output: 0

expected output: 5

Comment: Welcome, please show your code. See [mcve]. Show the answer you get and explain which answer you expect.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to attach my test code.

Comment: Please also show the input and the result.

Comment: I added. Thanks for advices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the input one character at a time and count the number read from `STDIN`.

```
program foo
  character(len=100) s
  integer i
  i = 1
  do
      read(*,'(A1)',eor=10,advance='no') s(i:i)
      i = i + 1
  end do
10 print *, i - 1  ! Minus for '\n'
end program foo
```

`TRIM` and `LEN_TRIM` will still get rid of trailing whitespace.
You can test that `s(i:i) == ' '` and then set it to some
printable character.

Comment: Really interesting. I didn't think of this. But it will do funny things when the user uses backspace, you will get strings like `i-1=8` `"         6�▒p���`��������▒�����@8���▒����▒f��▒▒"` In gfortran. In Intel Fortran it looks better.

Comment: Yes, odd things can happen as stdin is a preconnect unit, which the operating system may manage in some way.  I'm too lazy to write the code to use 'c' as a temporary and SELECT CASE(c) to throw out things like backspace.  Hmmm, just tested with gfortran on a UNIX-like system, I don't see the backspace issue that you show.

Comment: OK, it goes away if one initializes the string properly before reading.

Comment: It does not work correctly for backspace, or etc, but it is enough to handle only spaces. And based on your idea, I found that `read(*, '(100a)', eor=10, advance='no', size=cnt) s` is also available, where `cnt` is an integer variable. Thanks a lot!

Comment: That is probably the best.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways:

```
program test_getline
    use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env
    implicit none

    integer, parameter :: latin1 = selected_char_kind('ISO_10646')
    character(*), parameter :: fn = 'test_getline.tmp'

    character(30, kind=latin1) s
    integer i, ioss, sz, l

    open(unit=output_unit, encoding='utf-8')

    open(unit=10, file=fn, encoding='utf-8')
    write(10, '(a)') 'Für eigenständig Roß     '

    rewind(10)
        ! Read line character by character.
    l = len(s)
    do i = 1, len(s)
        read(10, '(a)', iostat=ioss, advance='no') s(i:i)
        if(ioss < 0) then
            l = i - 1
            exit
        end if
    end do
    print *, l, '"', s(:l), '"'

    rewind(10)
        ! Read line without padding, length null terminating string.
    s = repeat(char(0, latin1), len(s))
    read(10, '(a)', iostat=ioss, pad='no') s
    l = index(s, char(0, latin1)) - 1
    print *, l, '"', s(:l), '"'

    rewind(10)
        ! Count input character from file. 
        ! For UTF-8 encoding, it can be longer than the string length.
    read(10, '(a)', advance='no', iostat=ioss, size=sz) s
    print *, sz, '"', s(:sz), '"'

end program test_getline
```

Output:

```
      25 "Für eigenständig Roß     "
      25 "Für eigenständig Roß     "
      28 "Für eigenständig Roß        "
```

Comment: @francescalus , OK, change example and output. All three string readings are independent of the number and location of spaces.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand your question, you would like to include any trailing spaces the user included in his/her input into your query.

<strike>That is simply impossible in Fortran formatted I/O from standard input (from keyboard)</strike> - I was WRONG see @evets' answer - it is only true (I think now) for advancing output of complete lines. There is no way to distinguish the trailing space included by the user and the blanks normally used too pad all Fortran strings.

Therefore when `len_trim()` counts the length of the string it cuts away all trailing blanks including those entered by the user. The same holds for the `trim()` function.

Comment: I can't think of a way with formatted I/O from standard input. But I may be wrong.

Comment: Is there any good approach to this problem without formatted I/O?

Comment: If you can read from a text file you can read each byte separately. There are also ways how to read the input stream like a binary, but they are system-specific.

Comment: You could also try something like http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/iso_readline%283f%29 and access the full string from C.